# How can I set hibernate-reactive with application.yml or application.properties?

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, coroutine, hibernate-reactive

I want to config my datasource with application.yml or application.properties.
follow is my dependencies

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("io.vertx:vertx-mysql-client:4.2.5")
    implementation("org.hibernate.reactive:hibernate-reactive-core:1.1.3.Final")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen")
    testRuntimeOnly("com.wix:wix-embedded-mysql:4.6.2")
    .
    .
    .
}
```

#### My Purpose

I want to migrate following xml

```xml
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="mysql-example">
        <provider>org.hibernate.reactive.provider.ReactivePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>

            <!-- MySQL -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hreact"/>

            <!-- Credentials -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"
                      value="hreact"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                      value="hreact"/>

            <!-- The Vert.x SQL Client connection pool size -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size"
                      value="10"/>

            <!-- Automatic schema export -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                      value="drop-and-create"/>

            <!-- SQL statement logging -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <!--property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/-->

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Is there any way to migrate it?